# Why does vim autoindent work inconsistently

Tags: vim

Using vim 8.0.1365 on a Macintosh

I don't understand why autoindent fails some of the time.

Both of the code fragments below are indented as I want them to 
be when I run the formatter, (both default and the pangloss 
indenter).  But when I'm in insert mode, the autoindent 
doesn't work for the second code fragment.

So code like this gets autoindented as I'd like;

```
function SayHiToMom () {
    message = "Hello, best mom in the world";   <- This line auto-indents, as expected.
    send(message);                              <- and so does this one.
}
```

But not this code

```
 var svg = d3.select("#chart-area").append("svg")
     .attr("width", 400)   <- Here, no auto-indent occurs, but that's not really a surprise. I indent by hand.
     .attr("height", 400)  <- When I start a new line here, no auto-indent occurs, surprising and annoying.
```

Comment: Autoindent just tries to copy the previous line’s indent. It isnt smarter than that.

Comment: That's what's confusing:  In the second case, very last line, it does not copy the previous line indent.

Answer (score 0):

When you have filetype support on, Vim loads a filetype plugin when you load a file of a particular type (like JavaScript) and that file contains multiple settings.  In the case of JavaScript, one of those settings is `indentexpr`, which is a function that's called to automatically provide the right indent.

It appears that in this case, it doesn't handle that case automatically, possibly because nobody ever considered that case in the code.  Vim doesn't understand JavaScript natively, so the Vimscript has to do the best it can.

Also, it's possible that someone didn't do this behavior because your line wouldn't intrinsically be considered a continuation line if someone were using the JavaScript style where you don't write semicolons at the end, but instead put them at the beginning of the line if necessary to disambiguate.  Vim has to support both styles of JavaScript, even if not everyone agrees that both are a good idea.

Regardless, the header of the file (on my system, `/usr/share/vim/vim82/indent/javascript.vim`) contains a GitHub URL where you could report this issue and either send a patch or see if someone else would be willing to write one.  You could also turn off the `indentexpr` value by writing something like the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
au FileType javascript setl indentexpr=
```

In that case, you'd get the default `autoindent` behavior.